# How to set rs.slaveOk() in secondary mongodb servers in replicaset via commandline?

Tags: mongodb, replicaset

How to set rs.slaveOk() in secondary mongodb servers in replicaset via commandline?

I tried following methods :

`${MONGO_HOME}/bin/mongo --port ${MONGO_PORT2} --host ${MONGO_SECONDARY2} --eval "printjson(rs.slaveOk())"`

`${MONGO_HOME}/bin/mongo --port ${MONGO_PORT2} --host ${MONGO_SECONDARY2} --eval "printjson(rs.slaveOk(true))"`

`${MONGO_HOME}/bin/mongo --port ${MONGO_PORT2} --host ${MONGO_SECONDARY2} --eval "printjson(db.getSiblingDB('admin').getMongo().setSlaveOk())"`

the command executes with `undefined` in the output log.
I am trying to set this via the shell in primary server.

Comment: rs.slaveOk() does not have a return type. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: the return value part was misleading. when i try to execute the above mentioned command via a shell script, it doesn't work.

Comment: You keep saying things doesn't work, but provide no information on what you are trying to do and no error messages?!

Comment: I am trying to execute rs.slaveOk() in a secondary server via unix commandline. There are no errors, the code executes but the secondary server still can't accept reads.

Comment: setSlaveOk() does not change whether a replica will accepts reads. It enables a connection to be used for queries even if that connection is to a slave server, the setting has no effect on the server.

Comment: ok i get it now, i didn't read the docs correctly. Thanks for clarifying it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Create a file `/etc/mongorc.js` and add `rs.slaveOk()` there. The file is being evaluated on each shell startup.

For more information have a look [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongo/#mongo-mongorc-file)

From MongoDB version 4.4 onwards, you might get a warning displayed like:

`WARNING: slaveOk() is deprecated and may be removed in the next major release. Please use secondaryOk() instead.`

So, please prefer using `rs.secondaryOk()`

Answer (score 6):

Calling the below should work fine, there is no return type for the method so nothing will get printed back to the screen

```
${MONGO_HOME}/bin/mongo --port ${MONGO_PORT2} --host ${MONGO_SECONDARY2} --eval "rs.slaveOk()"
```

Running `rs.slaveOk` in the mongo.exe will also how how it is implemented as it is just a helper method:

```
> rs.slaveOk
function (value) { return db.getMongo().setSlaveOk(value); }
>
```

And also the `setSlaveOk` method:

```
> db.getMongo().setSlaveOk
function ( value ) {
     if( value == undefined ) value = true;
     this.slaveOk = value;
}
```

You could always try to query one of the collections on the secondary to make sure the node is queryable:

```
> db.test.findOne()
null
```

> **Update** - bit more clarity

Setting `slaveOk()` is only valid for that console session that it was executed in, so you would need to pass in a script or stay connected to the console with the `--shell` arguments for exmaple

```
C:\mongodb\bin>mongo.exe --port 27012 --eval "rs.slaveOk()" --shell
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.5
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:27012/test
type "help" for help
rs1:SECONDARY> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5630fdf2af4abd9f8ae7f79c"), "test" : true }
rs1:SECONDARY>
```

If we don't pass in the `rs.slaveOk()` the we get the following response:

```
C:\mongodb\bin>mongo.exe --port 27012 --shell
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.5
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:27012/test
type "help" for help
rs1:SECONDARY> db.test.find()
Error: error: { "$err" : "not master and slaveOk=false", "code" : 13435 }
rs1:SECONDARY> exit
bye
```

Comment: This doesn't work, this was the first method i tried. thanks though.

Comment: @NitheshKHP I've updated the answer just for a bit more clarity on the subject, hope it makes a little more sense now.

Comment: I like this ```db.getMongo().setSlaveOk()``` approach better as it is more scripting friendly.

Comment: Does anything named "slave" still exist in MongoDB in these politically correct times?

Answer (score 1):

JFYI :
looks like `rs.slaveOk()`  will be deprecated soon, instead MongoDB suggest to use `rs.secondaryOk()`

Following is the official warning you gonna see in MongoShell:

> WARNING: slaveOk() is deprecated and may be removed in the next major
> release. Please use secondaryOk() instead.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The `rs.slaveOk()` and `rs.secondaryOk()` are now deprecated (On `Mongodb6.0` and above).

So, Use this instead:

```
db.getMongo().setReadPref('secondary')
```