# mongodump with oplog unable to perform full backup

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, mongodb-query

I'm trying to perform a full backup of mongodb using the following command:

```
mongodump --uri="mongodb://mongo.database.svc:27017/?replicaSet=rs0"  --oplog --out=/mnt/k8sMount/mongodb-dump/
```

Note: Here the `uri` specified is a mongodb headless service in kubernetes.

But this command after few minutes results in error:

```
2021-10-08T02:55:19.021+0000    Failed: error counting admin.system.version: not master and slaveOk=false
```

I have gone through multiple forums regarding this error, but did not find relevant solution. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Note:
When i exec to the mongodb primary pod and run the command(here i dont specify the `uri` parameter), it works fine without any issues.

Mongodb version: 4

Comment: What happens here is when you are trying to get a dump, you specify a `replicaset uri` so  `mongodump` connects to NOT primary pod, but to a slave one. This is why you see this error. Options I see: connect to primary pod directly (depends on cluster and everything), try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33366182/how-to-set-rs-slaveok-in-secondary-mongodb-servers-in-replicaset-via-commandli) - not sure again it will work. Last is to ask a question on [mongo community forum](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/)